# how to Write / Replace Object to text file - Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, filereader

how do I replace an object in a text file and save it to the text file???

First I am adding the individual rooms.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size() - 1; i++){

    String[] words = lines.get(i).split(" ");
    var room = new Room();
    room.roomNum = Integer.parseInt(words[0]);
    room.roomType = (words[1]);
    room.roomPrice = Double.parseDouble(words[2]);
    room.hasBalcony = Boolean.parseBoolean(words[3]);
    room.hasLounge = Boolean.parseBoolean(words[4]);
    room.eMail = (words[5]);
    rooms.add(room);                   
}
```

Then I am searching for a specific room in the text file and replacing the selectedRoom.eMail with a reserveEmail.

```
System.out.println("\n-- ROOM RESERVATION --");
System.out.println("Please enter the room number you wish to reserve"); 

Room selectedRoom = null;
var searchRoomNum = input.nextInt();

for(int i = 0; i < rooms.size(); i++){                 
    if(rooms.get(i).roomNum == searchRoomNum){                    
        selectedRoom = rooms.get(i);     
    }
}

if(selectedRoom.eMail.contentEquals("free")) {  
    System.out.println("Please Enter your email");
        var reserveEmail = input.next();
            selectedRoom.eMail = reserveEmail;
            System.out.println("Thanks, this room has been reserved");
            return;
}
```

I need to know how to save this change to the text file it comes from without overwriting the entire file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your file, it might be easier to simply load it into memory, parse it into your Room objects, and overwrite your changes.

I apologize if my code has mistakes but I’m on mobile. It should give you the general algorithm for getting it going.

**Import Scanner**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

**General Update Process**

```
// Load to memory
Scanner scn = new Scanner(new File(“C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.txt”));

// Create new list of rooms
List<Room> roomList = new ArrayList<Room>();

// Begin parsing
while (scn.HasNextLine()) {
    String currentLine = scn.nextLine();
    String[] roomAttrs = currentLine.split(“ ”);
    Room currentRoom = new Room();
    currentRoom.roomNum = Integer.parseInt(roomAttrs[0]);
    currentRoom.roomType = roomAttrs[1];
    currentRoom.roomPrice = Double.parseDouble(roomAttrs[2]);
    currentRoom.hasBalcony = Boolean.parseBoolean(roomAttrs[3]);
    currentRoom.hasLounge = Boolean.parseBoolean(roomAttrs[4]);
    currentRoom.eMail = roomAttrs[5];

    // make your changes to the room here

    roomList.add(currentRoom);
}

// reuse code for writing to text here, either delete file or clear it
```